# CacheManager: Failed to download file from : with error: FormatException: Invalid empty scheme (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use [story_view](https://pub.dev/packages/story_view). But the image is not loading giving the exception in the question. I tried using `trim()` but still not working. I am getting following expection:

```
I/flutter ( 3447): CacheManager: Failed to download file from : with error:
I/flutter ( 3447): FormatException: Invalid empty scheme (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 3447): :
I/flutter ( 3447): ^
```

I have implemented as follows:

```
 Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .height * 0.14,
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: presenter.responseStories.value.data == null
                  ? 0
                  : presenter.responseStories.value.data.storyList.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return
                  InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        print(presenter
                            .responseStories.value.data.storyList[i].image);
                        return Stories(
                          presenter
                              .responseStories.value.data.storyList[i].image.trim(),
                          i,
                          presenter.responseStories.value.data.storyList.length,
                          presenter.responseStories.value.data.storyList[i]
                              .description,
                        );
                      }),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: RotationTransition(
                            turns: base,
                            child: DashedCircle(
                              gapSize: presenter.isConnectedToInternet
                                  ? gap.value
                                  : 20,
                              dashes: 20,
                              color: CustomColor.themeColor,
                              child: RotationTransition(
                                turns: reverse,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 30.0,
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(presenter
                                        .responseStories
                                        .value
                                        .data
                                        .storyList[i]
                                        .image),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

When clicking the item the story_view is loaded and I have implemented as follows:

```
   StoryView(
              controller: storyController,
              storyItems: [
                for (int i = widget.storiesLength;
                    i < widget.imageUrl.length;
                    i++)
                  StoryItem.inlineImage(
                    url: (widget.imageUrl[i]),
                    controller: storyController,
                    caption: Text(
                      widget.desc != null ? widget.desc : '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
              onStoryShow: (s) {
                print("Showing a story");
                print(s);
              },
              onComplete: () {
                print("Completed a cycle");
              },
              progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
              repeat: false,
              inline: true,
            ),
```

Comment: Can you add error message to the question? Also [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/336) is the similar issue.

Comment: I have editing my question @fartem

Comment: Are you sure that all links valid and available?

Comment: @fartem yes I tried pasting the url statically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this,it was due to passing wrong parameter

```
   StoryView(
          controller: storyController,
          storyItems: [
            for (int i = widget.stories; i < widget.imageUrl.length; i++)
              StoryItem.inlineImage(
              imageFit: BoxFit.contain,
                url: (widget.imageUrl[i].image),
                controller: storyController,
                caption: Text(
                  widget.desc != null ? widget.desc : '',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                    fontSize: 17,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
          onStoryShow: (s) {
            print("Showing a story");
            print(s);
          },
          onComplete: () {
            print("Completed a cycle");
          },
          progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
          repeat: false,
          inline: true,
        ),
```